# How to determine if a pattern of distribution is different from a random/uniform distribution

Tags: probability, spatial, glm, anova, heterogeneous

Here is my case:

Let's say we have 50 polygons(looks like this:
[image: 1]

and a point set distributed within these 50 polygons. So that for each polygon, there is an associated point density. What I want to test if whether the distribution pattern of this data set (for example, the fluctuations in density across 50 polygons) is kind of realization of spatial randomness.

The method I use is: in the uniform random case, the number of points of each ring follows a binomial distribution, i.e. X~B(n, p), where n is the total number of points and p is the probability of each point to be inside a particular polygon (p = Area_polygon/Area_semicircle). So that for each polygon, I can calculate the expected number of points and upon which we can calculate the density. And then I can apply the one-way ANOVA to compare two groups: the actual density group and the theoretical density group.

However, I found a problem: when calculating the density, I actually divide the expected number over the area. But, considering the expected number

> E = N(total number)*Area_polygon/total area,

thus the density:

> D = N(total number)/total area

which means for each polygon, the expected density is the same number.

So in that case, is it still suitable to use one-way ANOVA to compare my actual density group to a group within which all numbers are the same?

What if use numbers rather than density? Or is there any other more suitable tests?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look up a method called "quadrat test". It is explained in the online help for the function `quadrat.test` in the R package spatstat and more extensively in the [spatstat book](https://book.statstat.org).  (Disclaimer: I'm a coauthor.)

Comment: Hi Rubak, thank you for your reply. Quadrat test seems like something I need, but each of the study region is a polygon rather than a quadrat. Can I implement polygon also in quadrat.test function?

Comment: Yes, if you use `spatstat` you can easily do the test over polygonal regions by using the argument `tess`.